# Google Apps Script - Gmail Edit and, after, forward a message

Tags: gmail-api

Wherever I receive a message that contains "Nova reserva" in subject, I need to send an email to "accumakerapp-103@forms.zohocreator.com" with this EXACT format:

Remetente : (mail address of the sender)
Destinatário : (mail address of the receiver)
Assunto : (mail subject)
Texto : (mail body)

Someone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/). To be able to filter the required subject, use [`getSubject()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getSubject()). Then, when you already got the email that you needed using the method above proceed to create a reply message with your specified format using [`reply(body)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#reply(String)), [`reply(body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replyAll(String)), [`replyAll(body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replyAll(String,Object)) whichever is applicable/suit your requirements. Additionally, if you want to forward the exact message, use [forward(recipient, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)).